# How do I show each question part to show up at the top of the tikzpicture?

Tags: tikz-pgf, multicol, exam

I'm still quite new to latex, but I am typing up an exam which includes shapes of varying sizes. In each column, I would like the tops of the shapes to be aligned vertically, hopefully allowing the question numbers to also align (so that (a) is aligned to (b) and they are both at the top of their corresponding images and not at the bottom). This is my first time trying to make a MWE, it may not be perfect.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{exam}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{multicol}

    \begin{questions}
    \question Find the area of each figure shown below.
    \begin{parts}
        \begin{multicols}{2}
            \part{
                \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.3]
                    \draw (0,0) circle (4);
                    \draw (0,0) -- node[above]{4 m} (4,0);
                    \draw[fill=black] (0,0) circle (0.07);
                \end{tikzpicture}
                }
                
            \part{
            \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.3]
                    \draw (0,0) circle (8);
                    \draw (0,0) -- node[above]{8 mm} (8,0);
                    \draw[fill=black] (0,0) circle (0.07);
                \end{tikzpicture}
                }
        \end{multicols}
    \end{parts}
\end{questions}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

A solution is to give `baseline=(current bounding box.north)` as an option to the tikzpicture. Thus `\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.3,baseline=(current bounding box.north)]`.

According to the pgfmanual, the syntax `\draw (0,0) circle (4);` is old. The newer syntax is `\draw (0,0) circle [radius=4];`.

Instead of the text `4 m` in the node (and similarly for `8 mm`), consider using the siunitx package with `\usepackage{siunitx}` and then `\qty{4}{\m}` for the text. Then the spacing between `4` and `m` will not be as large compared to `4 m`.

Instead of `\draw[fill=black]`, `\fill` can be used.